# Async Actions Reducer Typings using typesafe-actions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I'm having a small difficulty in using `createAsyncAction` from the module `typesafe-actions` ([Typesafe Actions](https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions/)) and typing them the same for my reducer

Here is the action

```
export const login = createAsyncAction(
    EmployeeConstants.LOGIN.REQUEST,
    EmployeeConstants.LOGIN.SUCCESS,
    EmployeeConstants.LOGIN.ERROR
)<ILoginRequest,ILoginSuccess, Error>();
```

As you can see, this creates an async action builder `AsyncActionBuilder`, and not the actions themselves.

And my reducer is typed by doing like so

```
import * as loginActions from './actions';

type IEmployeeActions = ActionType<typeof loginActions>;

const employeeState = (state = initialState, action: IEmployeeActions) => {
  // switch cases
}
```

But I'm not able to access `payload` or `type` (obviously) because `loginActions` is a union of async builders and not Actions themselves.

How do I resolve them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, what I have is actually correct, but I had a bad implementation while creating the constants in `createAsyncAction`

I was dynamically generating constants like below:

```
function createAsyncTypes(type: string) {
    return {
        REQUEST: type + "_REQUEST",
        SUCCESS: type + "_SUCCESS",
        ERROR: type + "_ERROR"
    }
}
```

And the TS server could not compute that during linting and it caused a mess during the chaining.

I changed them to this,

```
export const login = createAsyncAction(
    "LOGIN_REQUEST",
    "LOGIN_SUCCESS",
    "LOGIN_FAILURE"
)<ILoginRequest, ILoginSuccess, Error>();
```

And TS Server validly shows the exports